# SQL return an integer instead of an error message with a unique constraint

Tags: c#, sql, return

I have a unique constraint on an email field in my table.
I made a stored procedure that is supposed to return 0 if there was an error and 1 if there wasn't.

```
ALTER procedure [S_User].[P_RegisterUser]
@email varchar(50),
@last_name varchar(50),
@first_name varchar(20),
@password varchar(50),
@birthday datetime
AS
BEGIN
insert into Users (email, last_name, first_name, password, birthday, role_id)
values (@email, @last_name, @first_name,@password, @birthday, 1)

IF @@ERROR <> 0
    RETURN 0
ELSE
    RETURN 1
END
```

Instead of returning the integer, it returns an error message:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure P_RegisterUser, Line 11
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'uq_users_email'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (sir_bonbon@hotmail.com).
The statement has been terminated.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

In my C# code, it throws an exception because it didn't get the integer but rather the error.
How can I do to correctly return the integer?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your C# code look like..? also before doing the insert.. why don't you do a Select email and check for a count > 0 if so do not allow the Insert.. also you could create an OutParameter to return the error code.. as well..

Comment: You can use [Try-Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) in T-SQL

Comment: why dont you check it manually, whether there is a duplicate, sometimes, the error may be something else, dont need to confuse, check it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try catch in your stored procedure : [see the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175976(v=sql.120).aspx)
You just need to return 0 in the catch and 1 after the catch block.

You can also handle the exception in your code. It seems the best option to me.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like your insert statement is throwing an exception. 
you can just catch that exception and return a 0 or 1 right?

add ...

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        RETURN 0
```

-- right before END.

Comment: I prefer the try/catch version, EXCEPTION didn't work for me in SQL (but I'm very noob so I probably did something wrong). Thanks anyway!